# Display floating UL with the left of the list lined up with the immediate text field above

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I need help with CSS to display a list of values perhaps in an unordered list  lined up with the immediate text field above it.

This fragment of code consists of HTML, javascript/jquery and JSON data to work with.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="30" onKeyUp="javascript:displayList();" />
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="30" onKeyUp="javascript:displayList();" />
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="30" onKeyUp="javascript:displayList();" />
            <td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <ul id="localityList"></ul>
</div>




var dataObj = {
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "severity": "NORMAL",
            "text": ""
        },
        "target_value": ""
    },
    "locality": [{
        "locId": "31110",
        "name": "Mont Albert",
        "alias": "ALERT",
        "event": "A",
        "state": "on"
    }, {
        "locId": "31111",
        "name": "Mt Macedone",
        "alias": "MACEDON",
        "event": "A",
        "state": "off"
    }, {
        "locId": "31112",
        "name": "Mornington Pen.",
        "alias": "MORNINGTON",
        "event": "B",
        "state": "on"
    }, {
        "locId": "31113",
        "name": "Mt Pleasant",
        "alias": "PLEASANT",
        "event": "C",
        "state": "on"
    }, {
        "locId": "31114",
        "name": "Kanga I",
        "alias": "KANGAROO",
        "event": "I",
        "state": "on"
    }, ]
};


function distribute(pThis) {
    //console.log($(pThis).find('td.liLocId').text());
}

function displayList() {
    locality = dataObj.locality;
    $("#localityList").empty('li');
    var li = "";
    $.each(locality, function (i, o) {
        li += '<li class="clsLocList" onClick="javascript:distribute(this);"><table><tr><td class="liLocId">' + locality[i].locId + '</td><td class="liLocName">' + locality[i].name + ' (' + locality[i].alias + ')</td></tr></table></li>';
    });

    $("#localityList").append(li);
}
```

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ukhN/

Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You've to override the browser specific styles… 
Simply apply

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ukhN/1/)

*Side notes:*

- you might want to close the  tags
- Instead of adding an entire table inside an `<li>` you can simply use some `<span>`s to create the same layout, table rendering will be slower afaik.

Comment: TJ, thanks for your help. I didn't explain clearly. I need something like a div that floats so that it doesn't matter where the text box is when it displays it aligns to the left lining up with the immediate text box above. I'm trying to achieve the result that is similar to Google search autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the floating UL (wrapped within a DIV), the position of the text field is determined and then this position is used as a base for deriving the new position for the DIV to display relative to the text field. In this case, it is aligned to the left.

To work out the position of an element use. Here's a hack:

```
var item = $(pItem);
console.log("displayDiv.pItem.id:" + pItem.id);
var pos = item.offset();
pos.bottom = pos.top + item.height();
pos.right = pos.left + item.width();

var top = pos.bottom + 10;
var left = pos.left;

$("#ulDiv").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2000,
    left: left,
    top: top
});
$('#ulDiv').show();
```

Updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ukhN/

Cheers